# FTP File transfer With Chinese Characters

Tags: ftp, character-encoding

When I'm trying to send files with Chinese characters over ftp, I am getting:

```
500 ERROR (Internal Server ERROR)
```

through my backend code; It's working fine for english characters but not for Chinese. What is the best possible way to send those files with Chinese names  over FTP? 
Thanks in advance hope best will come.

Comment: Which operating systems on both ends and which ftp products for server and client.

Comment: Server deployed  on AWS server and for client its windows OS

Comment: Chinese-character files should be transferred using binary mode, e.g. per https://www.jscape.com/blog/ftp-binary-and-ascii-transfer-types-and-the-case-of-corrupt-files and many many others.

Answer (score 1):

The File Transfer Protocol, as defined in
[RFC959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) and later,
is one of the oldest protocols on the Internet, using as primary character set
the 7-bit ASCII.
International characters need a protocol that uses Unicode.
Such a protocol is the
[SSH File Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol)
or SFTP, proposed in [RFC2640](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2640).

Using an SFTP client, you would be using the UTF-8 protocol on both client and
server (if their implementation follows the standard).
Windows 10 contains the command-line utility `sftp`.
Or as alternative you could use a third-party utility such as the free
[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use FTP [binary transfer](https://www.jscape.com/blog/ftp-binary-and-ascii-transfer-types-and-the-case-of-corrupt-files), rather than ASCII (ANSI) and zip files to hide filenames.

Comment: but if i do send them in zip,  zipped folder name must be in Chinese. so here the problem is same again . i have not sure about that my server support FTP  binary transfer, so i will try that too.  and thanks for your valueable response and time

Comment: Windows does not support certain characters in filenames, e.g. forward slash and colon. Perhaps some multibyte Chinese characters contain illegal characters. Are there versions of Chinese, e.g. Hanyu Pinyin, that are more usable?

Comment: we need to send those files and folders with smiplifed chinese characters

Comment: Test which characters cause issues and don't use 'em.